# Deploying a .zip file with my .NET MAUI app

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app and I want to copy a resource file (let's say a .zip) along with my app. Meaning that when my app is installed, the file is copied into the device.

I don't want to use an `Embedded Resource`, I want the file copied as it is and then access it by using it's completed path.

1. Where should I put the file in the solution? In the Shared Resource folder or in every platform?
2. Which `Build Action` should I use?

Comment: generally speaking, I would include the file in the root of my project with build type of "Content".  No idea if this would still work in MAUI

Answer (score 0):

you can try with MauiAsset instead of Embedded Resource. You can read about this here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-maui-preview-4/

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me...